# Imagick with SVG from HTML-Domnode

Tags: php, svg, imagick

I'm trying to convert a svg-image via php out of an html-string.

```
$im = new Imagick();
$svgNode = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?><svg id='mySVG' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1'><g id='viewport'></g></svg>";
$im->readimageblob($svgNode);
```

Only these 3 lines cause an error:

```
no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-ao323XDs' @ error/svg.c/ReadSVGImage/2871\n
```

I don't know whats my mistake. The xml is there, the svg is the simplest I can imaginge ^^.

Answer (score 0):

The library under Imagick that actually processes the images, ImageMagick, requires you to set the size of an SVG image through the width and height attributes e.g. this works:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$svgNode = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='no'?>
<svg id='mySVG' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' version='1.1' width='158px' height='92px'>
<g id='viewport'></g>
</svg>";
$im->readimageblob($svgNode);
```

Comment: Hi. With this example it works now. With the data that comes urlencoded from requestpayload it doesn't work.                                  <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1834" height="910">        <g id="viewport">            </g></svg>               This comes urlencoded. In PHP I do: $request_body = file_get_contents('php://input'); $im = new Imagick(); $svgNode = substr($request_body,8); $im->readimageblob(urldecode($svgNode)); Exception abgefangen: no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/blob.c/BlobToImage/

Comment: @dobberph That isn't valid SVG or XML. It has an erroneous semi-colon in the opening SVG block.